# How do I convert a string to Date Time in a particular format in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert "1/7/2014 1:37 PM" (which is a string) to "01/07/2014 13:37" (DateTime format). What would be the best way to do this?

This is what I've got

```
        string dateString = "1/27/2014 1:37 PM"; 
        string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
        DateTime dt;
        bool temp = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
        Console.WriteLine("bool = {0}, dt ={1}", temp, dt);
```

And my output is

```
        bool = False, dt =1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Much thanks.

EDIT:

It's not just for the string I specified. Adding a few more cases - The LHS should get parsed exactly to the RHS

```
    1/7/2014 1:37 PM -> 01/07/2014 13:37

    11/27/2014 1:40 AM -> 11/27/2014 01:40

    1/12/2014 2:05 PM -> 01/12/2014 14:05
```

Essentially, the input string does not have leading zeros and time is in 12 hour format and the output should have leading zeros where needed and should display the time in 24 hour format

I've tried giving

```
    string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt";
```

but that also gives the same wrong output

```
    bool = False, dt =1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Once you've converted to a `DateTime`, it doesn't **have** a format. a `DateTime` value is the count of the number of 100 nanosecond intervals that have occurred since 01/01/0001 and an indicator of whether it thinks it's UTC, a Local time, or it doesn't know. How that `DateTime` appears when you convert it back into a string is entirely at the mercy of whatever code you write to convert it into a string (either directly or by using format strings)

Answer (score 4):

Four things to change:

1. You need lowercase `h` for hours if you use the am/pm designator
2. You need a single `h` if the hour can be `1`
3. You need to add `tt` for the am/pm designator
4. You need a single `M` for the month since it's `1`

---

```
string dateString = "1/27/2014 1:37 PM"; 
string format = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt";
DateTime dt;
bool temp = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

Console.Write("temp: {0} date:{1}", temp, dt); // temp: True date:1/27/2014 1:37:00 PM
```

See: [The "tt" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ttSpecifier)

**Update**: acccording to your edit:

> I also need to convert it back to string in a specific format. It should have leading zeros and time is in 12 hour format and the output should have leading zeros where needed and should display the time in 24 hour format

```
1/7/2014 1:37 PM -> 01/07/2014 13:37
11/27/2014 1:40 AM -> 11/27/2014 01:40
1/12/2014 2:05 PM -> 01/12/2014 14:05
```

Then you can use this format string: `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` in `DateTime.ToString` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Note that i've used uppercase `HH` for 24h hour format:

```
string output = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You need `InvariantCulture`, otherwise `/` will be replaced with the actual date-separator of your current culture (f.e. `.` in germany).

See: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

Comment: Works brilliant thanks! Two small things though: 1) It should be string format = "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt" since date can also be single digit. And 2) It should be MM/dd and not dd/MM in the final ToString conversion.

Comment: 1) 11 is the month (November), not the date. 27 is the date. so the format is MM/dd, not dd/MM         2) I meant the single 'd' not the single 'M', you have used 'dd' in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try like this

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong. You are missing the AM/PM:

```
string format = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt";
```

Notice the `tt` part which is required in order to be able to properly parse the date. Also I would recommend you adding error checking:

```
string dateString = "1/27/2014 1:37 PM"; 
string format = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt";
DateTime dt;
bool temp = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
if (temp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bool = {0}, dt = {1:M/dd/yyyy h:mm}", temp, dt);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse date: {0}", dateString);
}
```

Comment: Not sure but you should use `h` instead of `HH` for 12h time? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Candide No, the answer is missing several other problems with the format string.

Comment: @Rawling, I stand corrected, anyways, a minor oversight since the tt was the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

From [`DateTime.TryParseExact method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format, culture-specific
>   format information, and style. **The format of the string representation
>   must match the specified format exactly.**

In your case, it is not.

- [`MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MM_Specifier) format is for `01` to `12`, use [`M`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier) format which is `1` to `12`.
- [`HH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) format is for `00` to `23`, use [`h`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hSpecifier) format instead which is `1` to `12`.

Also you are missing [`tt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ttSpecifier) format which is for `AM/PM` designator.

```
string str  = "1/27/2014 1:37 PM";
string format = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt";
DateTime dt;
bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(str,
                                     format,
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                     DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output will be

```
True
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/vPFECZ)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

- lowercase `h` rather than `H` as the time is in 12-, not 24-hour
- one `h` rather than two as you don't have a leading zero on the hour
- one `M` rather than two as you don't have a leading zero on the month
- `tt` to match AM or PM.

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 Datetime dtDate = DateTime.PareExact(dt,"DateFormat of dt",cultureInfo.InavriantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string dateString = "1/27/2014 1:37 PM";
                string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";


                DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);

                Console.WriteLine(dt2.ToString(format));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:-

```
DateTime txtmyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm",     
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```